# 'str' object is not callable in csv import pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-colaboratory

I am trying to import CSV in Google Colab using pandas but failed

I have attached code here:

```
import pandas as pd 
labels_df=pd.read_csv(r'.\data\train_labels.csv')
#labels_df=pd.read_csv(path2csv)
labels_df.head()
```

This is error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-b4781c7a6dff> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 
----> 3 labels_df=pd.read_csv(r'.\data\train_labels.csv')
      4 #labels_df=pd.read_csv(path2csv)
      5 labels_df.head()

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you do `pd.read_csv = ''` somewhere?

Comment: yes the first line

Comment: That is your issue, you changed the function to a string. Why would you do that anyway?

Comment: '''
path2csv="./dataAws/train_labels.csv"
labels_df=pd.read_csv(path2csv)
'''
I tried this way but error is still there

Comment: Because you didn't fix the issue. Don't do `pd.read_csv = ''`

Comment: then what it should be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247727/discussion-between-leo90-and-guy).

Comment: It should be nothing, don't do it.

Comment: but there is new error 

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-35f639f34a90> in <module>
      3 path2csv="./dataAws/train_labels.csv"
      4 labels_df=path2csv
----> 5 labels_df.head()

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: Because you assign `path2csv` to `labels_df`... `labels_df=path2csv`

Comment: I want to print Head of dataset then what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

'''

```
import pandas as pd 

labels_df=pd.read_csv("../dataAws/train_labels.csv")
labels_df.head()
```

'''
I restarted kernel and it worked

Answer (score -1):

The following code works on a new Colab notebook:

```
import pandas as pd 
labels_df = pd.read_csv('./sample_data/california_housing_train.csv')
labels_df.head()
```

Notice the path variable uses forward slash '/' and not backslash '\' but using a backslash should produce a FileNotFoundError and not TypeError so I'm guessing there is some other problem not shown in your question.

Comment: import pandas as pd 

labels_df = pd.read_csv('./dataAws/train_labels.csv')
#labels_df=pd.read_csv(path2csv)
labels_df.head()

I tried this way too but same error

Comment: This is incorrect, using raw string `r` will solve any escaping issue.